# Tweaking a ranking algorithm from a few variables

Tags: algorithms, database

I'm going to have a mySQL table with elements in it and would like to rank them in the same manner than Reddit but not quite. I'd like to know how to add or remove importance to a variable in my ranking algorithm.

For instance, what I have is a time (a timestamp, so a huge value) and a number of upvotes (a smallish value, under 50). How do I give more importance to the upvotes and less to the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply each value with a weight, the timestamp will be small while the number of upvotes will be large.

Comment: Some something like `rank = 0.001*timestamp + 10*upvotes`?

Comment: @Farid exactly like that.

Comment: I suspect you really want a factor proportional to `(now - timestamp)`, and not directly `timestamp`.

Comment: @aecolley depends if he want older to be more important or less important: now-timestamp vs timestamp-epoch

Comment: @aecolley @ratchet freak I want older to be less important. Is it `timestamp-epoch`?

Comment: @Farid no that is for newer, for older you want `now - timestamp`